# how to choose whole people's record if the special course meets given score condition

Tags: python, pandas

For example, choose the persons whose score on `math` is greater than 80. Please note, it means if there are `math` courses in one person, then any of the `math` should > 80. I don't mean "choose only `math` > 80".

I can coin the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Mike', 'math 1', 30],
        ['Mike', 'math 2', 85],
        ['Mike', 'English writing', 70],
        ['Mike', 'English reading', 60],
        ['Mike', 'Java programming', 80],
        ['John', 'math 1', 85],
        ['John', 'math 2', 90],
        ['John', 'Python programming', 60],
        ['Einstein', 'math 1', 90],
        ['Einstein', 'math 3', 95],
        ['Einstein', 'C programming', 90],
    ],
    columns =['name', 'course', 'score']
)

lstDfResult = []

for name in set(df.name):
    dfTmp = df.query(f'name == "{name}"')
    dfTmpCourse = dfTmp[  dfTmp['course'].str.contains('math')  ]
    if len(dfTmpCourse[dfTmpCourse.score>80]) == len(dfTmpCourse):
       lstDfResult.append(dfTmp)

dfResult = pd.concat(lstDfResult)

print(dfResult)
```

if the condition gets more complex, for example, choose the persons whose score on `math` is greater than 80 `AND` score on `engish` is greater than 60. The code goes longer.

Is there any terse but fast way to do so in pandas? Thanks

the original df

| name | course | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | math 1 | 30 |
| Mike | math 2 | 85 |
| Mike | English writing | 70 |
| Mike | English reading | 60 |
| Mike | Java programming | 80 |
| John | math 1 | 85 |
| John | math 2 | 90 |
| John | Python programming | 60 |
| Einstein | math 1 | 90 |
| Einstein | math 3 | 95 |
| Einstein | C programming | 90 |

the result form only one condition(`math` > 80)

| name | course | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Einstein | math 1 | 90 |
| Einstein | math 3 | 95 |
| Einstein | C programming | 90 |
| John | math 1 | 85 |
| John | math 2 | 90 |
| John | Python programming | 60 |

Comment: If a person doesn't have an English course, should it still be selected when *English score > 60* is imposed?

Comment: no, a person, who does not study English, should not been included because `English` > 60 is not satisfied

Comment: The result is what you expect or the result of your code? If this is the expected outcome, it's not according to your comment.

Comment: the above result uses only `math` > 80.

Answer (score 2):

Use `concat` to build a list where each requirement is satisfied independently then select rows that match all requirements.

This solution was greatly improved by @jezrael!

```
requirements = [('math', 80), ('programming', 70)]

mask = pd.concat([df.loc[df['course'].str.contains(course), 'score']
                    .gt(score).groupby(df['name']).all().rename(course)
                      for course, score in requirements], axis=1)

out = df[df['name'].isin(mask.index[mask.all(axis=1)])]
```

```
>>> mask
           math  programming
name
Einstein   True         True
John       True        False
Mike      False         True

>>> out
        name         course  score
8   Einstein         math 1     90
9   Einstein         math 3     95
10  Einstein  C programming     90
```

*Note*: according to your comment, no one satisfies the requirements:

- math > 80
- English > 60

Simplier solution:

```
m = pd.concat([df.loc[df['course'].str.contains(course), 'score']
                .gt(score).groupby(df['name']).all() 
                   for course, score in tups], axis=1)

names = m.index[m.all(axis=1)]

df = df[df['name'].isin(names)]
```

Comment: I think in term of perfromance this is better solution like `groupby.filter`, it is really, really slow.

Comment: @jezrael. Very clever. Don't know why i didn't think about it!!!

Answer (score 1):

With filter functions:

```
def make_filter(crs, scr):
    """
    Factory function that returns a filtering function
    """
    def f(gr):
        # first filter the group
        course_scores = gr.loc[gr["course"].str.contains(crs, case=False), "score"]
        filtered = course_scores > scr
        # it can be empty; e.g., person doesn't have English course
        if filtered.empty:
            return False
        else:
            # if not empty, return if all related course scores are okay
            return filtered.all()
    # returning the inner function
    return f

# requirements
courses = ["math", "programming"]
scores = [80, 70]

filters = [*map(make_filter, courses, scores)]

# GroupBy.filter selects those names that satisfy the requirements
result = df.groupby("name").filter(lambda gr: all(f(gr) for f in filters))
```

We first define a function that produces filtering function given the pair course-threshold score. Above, for example, we require Math and Programming course scores be greater than 80 and 70. `map` helps make a filter for each pair. Lastly `GroupBy.filter` looks for each name and applies each filter; we check if `all` the filters give `True` to decide whether to keep the group.

```
>>> result

        name         course  score
8   Einstein         math 1     90
9   Einstein         math 3     95
10  Einstein  C programming     90
```

Only *Einstein* had all Math scores > 80 and Programming > 70.